# Python - How does the index in the __next__() method work?

Tags: python, list, iterator, iteration

Can someone explain to me how the `__iter__()` and `__next__()` functions handle indices? Are they base `0` or base `1`?

I have been playing around with it, but I'd like to know what Python is actually doing on the back end. I tried the example class below:

```
>>> class my_class:
        def __init__(self, *stuff):
            self.__stuff = stuff

        def __iter__(self):
            self.__n = 0
            return iter(self.__stuff)

        def __next__(self):
            if self.__n <= len(self.__stuff):
                self.__n += 1
                return self.__stuff(self.__n)
            else:
                raise StopIteration

>>> x = my_class(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> for each in x:
        print(each)
1
2
3
4
```

Unless, I'm mistaken, the first `self.__n` value that `__next__()` uses should be `1`, which *should* produce, this:

```
>>> for each in x:
        print(each)
2
3
4
```

What am I missing? How does it know to start at `self.__stuff[0]`?

Comment: There are a couple of confusions here. Firstly, you generally want an iterable type to return an instance of another, specialized iterator type. So, `iter([1,2,3])` returns a `list_iterator` object. Second, your implementation of `__iter__` simply delegates to `self.__stuff`, which is always a tuple in this case, hence your `__next__` method never comes into the picture. Finally, don't use double-underscore name-mangling unless you *want* double-underscore name-mangling. Private variables are single-underscore by convention.

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided a little more background. This came up because I'm working on a project in which my classes have a lot of calculated attribute values that are interdependent, hence, I'm trying to use a lot of encapsulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `for each in x:`, it do nothing with `__next__()` in your class definition, so it start 1 of your object attribute rather than 2.

Even it you want to call something like `print(next(x))` it will give you 'TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable', because `self.__stuff(self.__n)` is invalid as in `self.__stuff` is a tuple and `self.__n` is an integer. You can only call `tuple[int]` rather than `tuple(int)`.

Try following code after your code mentioned it will return you desired output then raise an exception.

```
for each in x:    
    print(next(x))
```

Result:

```
2
3
4
raise StopIteration
```

Comment: I was just about to type up something similar, and was going to suggest to convince yourself by putting a print('am I called?') inside the def __next__

Comment: `self.__stuff(self.__n)` is not invalid syntax. it calls whatever is returned by `self.__stuff`, which may raise a type error because it isn't callable, but the *syntax* is fine.

Comment: @  juanpa.arrivillaga, True it is type error. Changed, sir.

Comment: Ah, so I should declare it as `self.__stuff = list(stuff)` for it to make use of the `__next__()` method?

Comment: @AndyPerez no, to make it make use of the `__next__` method then `__iter__` *would have to simply `return self`* as iterators are *required* to do. But you probably just want an *iterable*, not an *iterator*.

Comment: Oh, I see. I also see that I should turn the `self.__stuff` attribute into a list, *and* I need to  fix the index reference to use brackets.

Answer (score 2):

- When you use `my_class`, it first calls the `__init__`, then calls the `__iter__`, last is the `__next__`.
- In your code, when it calls `__iter__`, it `return iter(self.__stuff)`,then is over, `__next__` is not called. So the output is what you see.
- If you want `__next__` called, you can change your code like this(here self.__n that `__next__` uses starts from 1):

  ```
  class my_class:
      def __init__(self, *stuff):
        self.__stuff = stuff

      def __iter__(self):
        self.__n = 0
        print('__iter__ is called')
        return self

      def __next__(self):
        print('__next__ is called')
        if self.__n <= len(self.__stuff):
            self.__n += 1
            return self.__stuff(self.__n)
        else:
            raise StopIteration
  ```
- Tip: you can use `print` to help you understand what the code is doing, like `print` function in the code above.

Comment: Ah, okay. I think I was under the impression that the `__next__()` method was required for including an `__iter__()` method in the class. For my application, I don't even really need it. However, if I *did* need it, it looks like I was just incorrectly calling the index and should include the `return` on `__next__()` as `return self.__stuff[self.__n]`. Right?

Comment: You're right. `__next()__` is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The `__iter__()` method returns `iter(self.__stuff)` instead of `self`. As such, the tuple passed to `__init__()` is iterated over, not the object.